# Use WiX browser dialog to set edit box value

Tags: wix

I'm trying to create a WiX installer dialog that provides a series of textboxes that users need to fill in with directory locations.

What I would like to do is put a Browse button next to each dialog and when they click it, the WiX Browse dialog will come up, they select a file location, click OK, and the text box next to the browse button will be filled in.

I know how to do it with a custom action, but I was wondering if there was a pure WiX way of doing this.

EDIT: I should be more clear. I meant directory locations, not file locations. Wix doesn't have file browsing support as one user indicated below.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found a way to do it completely in WiX. WiX comes with a browse dialog called `BrowseDlg`. Here's what I did:

1. I created a dialog that includes a `PathEdit` control and `PushButton` control. Notice that the `PathEdit` control has the Indirect property set to yes. This means that whatever you set Property to is just a pointer to something else.

   ```
        <Dialog Id="BackupConfigDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="Backup Configuration">
            <Control Type="Text" Id="lblInstructions" Width="348" Height="13" X="10" Y="10">
                <Text>{\WixUI_Font_Title}Please select the directory you want to backup.</Text>
            </Control>
            <Control Type="Text" Id="lblBackupDirectory" Width="69" Height="9" X="10" Y="40" Text="Backup directory:">
            </Control>
            <Control Type="PathEdit" Id="Folder" Width="219" Height="15" X="82" Y="38" Property="_BrowseProperty" Indirect="yes" />
            <Control Type="PushButton" Id="Browse" Width="56" Height="17" X="304" Y="37" Text="Browse..." />
            <Control Type="Line" Id="line" Width="362" Height="2" X="4" Y="229" />
            <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="239" Y="240" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="Cancel">
                <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
            </Control>
            <Control Type="PushButton" Id="Install" Width="56" Height="17" X="300" Y="240" Text="Install">
                <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" />
            </Control>
        </Dialog>
   ```
2. The browse dialog (that we'll eventually get to) expects to set an object in the Directory table, so we need to create a Directory object that will only be used to hold the value we browse to. Since we won't put any components in it, nothing on the file system will change relating to the directory we choose. I call mine TARGETBACKUPDIRECTORY.

   ```
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="TARGETBACKUPDIRECTORY">
            </Directory>
            ...
        </Directory>
   ```
3. Now we need to create a property that points to the Directory object.

   ```
    <Property Id="BACKUPDIRECTORY" Value="TARGETBACKUPDIRECTORY" />
   ```
4. We now need to make sure that the _BrowserProperty property is properly bound to BACKUPDIRECTORY (because it points to the Directory object we want set) before this dialog opens. If you don't, you will get an error during the install process when you attempt to open the dialog. In my example, PrevDlg is a dialog that appears before BackupConfigDlg. What's happening here is that when the Next button is pushed, I set the _BrowserProperty property to BACKUPDIRECTORY, I then open the dialog. It must take place in that order so I use the Order property to enforce it. I do the same thing when the browse button is pushed, not sure I need to do, but I do it just for safe measure.

   ```
        <Publish Dialog="PrevDlg" Control="Next" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[BACKUPDIRECTORY]" Order="1">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="PrevDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="BackupConfigDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="BackupConfigDlg" Control="Browse" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[BACKUPDIRECTORY]" Order="1">
        </Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="BackupConfigDlg" Control="Browse" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">
        </Publish>
   ```

That's what worked for me.

Comment: I keep getting this error: "DEBUG: Error 2819:  Control Folder on dialog BackupConfigDlg needs a property linked to it
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2819. The arguments are: BackupConfigDlg, Folder, ". Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Never mind. It's funny because I've been struggling for a few hours and then I realized that I wasn't binding _BrowseProperty right. My 'BackupConfigDlg' is between SetupTypeDlg and VerifyReadyDlg and thus I need a an entry for each installation type button.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It was very helpful for me. But I would like to change the PathEdit control to Text control. But it does not show any string on my installer. Why does it not work as well as the PathEdit? How can I get it I want to do?

Answer (score 17):

*The selected answer to this question is way too much work. You don't need to do all that.*

Set your `PathEdit` control to the directory to configure as you normally would. Then, in the actions of the browse button, set `_BrowseProperty` to the NAME (not value of) of your property to configure and then `SpawnDialog`. That's it.

```
<Control Type="PathEdit"
         Id="TxtDir"
         Width="155" Height="15"
         X="105" Y="57"
         Property="OUTPUTDIRECTORY"/>
<Control Id="btnDirBrowse"
         Type="PushButton"
         Width="56" Height="17"
         X="260" Y="57"
         Text="Browse..." >
  <Publish Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="OUTPUTDIRECTORY" Order="1">1</Publish>
  <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
</Control>
```

Comment: "...Set your PathEdit control to the directory to configure as you normally would..." Could you expand on this, as I'm new to Wix and not sure how to normally do this. I'm not sure if you're using the term 'property' interchangeably with 'directory'. When you specify the 'NAME' of the property (versus the value), do you mean the 'Id'?

Comment: @Lumirris Normally setting up a `PathEdit` control, you set the `Property` attribute to the Id/Name of the property that will store the path. The Id/Name in the above example is `OUTPUTDIRECTORY`, the value of the property is `[OUTPUTDIRECTORY]`.

Comment: So are you saying that defining a `<Directory>` element is not needed (simply a `<Property>` element)? In your critique of the accepted answer, which aspects of that proposed solution are unnecessary?

Comment: No, it is not needed. The juggling of multiple properties for the same thing. The events on entering and leaving the dialog are unnecessary also.

Comment: @bit, That error is "The directory entry '[2]' does not exist in the Directory table." Probably need to create a Directory element for your property.

Comment: @NickWhaley, yep figured that out. Thanks!

Comment: Worked fine for me as well with multiple directories in the same dialog window after entering a directory entry for the property.

Answer (score 5):

In order to have multiple directories (filled by the BrowseDlg) in the same dialog window, an extra indirection is required. Notice also the numbering within the <Publish></Publish> tags  :

```
<Control Id="WorkingDirFolderLabel"        Type="Text"           Width="220" Height="12" X="10"  Y="50" Text="Working directory:"/>
<Control Id="WorkingDirFolder"             Type="PathEdit"       Width="250" Height="17" X="10"  Y="62" Property="_WorkingDirBrowseProperty" Indirect="yes"/>
<Control Id="WorkingDirBrowse"             Type="PushButton"     Width="56"  Height="17" X="265" Y="62" Text="Browse..." >
    <Publish Property="_BrowseProperty"  Value="[_WorkingDirBrowseProperty]"  Order="2">1</Publish>
    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="3">1</Publish>
</Control>

<Control Id="DocsDirFolderLabel"        Type="Text"           Width="220" Height="12" X="10"  Y="100" Text="Documentation area:"/>
<Control Id="DocsDirFolder"             Type="PathEdit"       Width="250" Height="17" X="10"  Y="112" Property="_DocsDirBrowseProperty" Indirect="yes" />
<Control Id="DocsDirBrowse"             Type="PushButton"     Width="56"  Height="17" X="265" Y="112" Text="Browse..." >
    <Publish Property="_BrowseProperty"  Value="[_DocsDirBrowseProperty]"  Order="2">2</Publish>
    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="3">2</Publish>
</Control>
```

Then pass the references as before (no need to define extra properties) :

```
<Publish Dialog="PrevDlg" Control="Next" Property="_WorkingDirBrowseProperty" Value="TARGETWORKINGDIRECTORY" Order="1">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="PrevDlg" Control="Next" Property="_DocsDirBrowseProperty" Value="TARGETDOCSDIRECTORY" Order="1">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="PrevDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="BackupConfigDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
```

Comment: What purpose does the numbering between the `<Publish></Publish>` tags have? How are they different from the `Order` attribute?

Answer (score 2):

Windows Installer doesn't support file browsing, so there is no direct support for this in WiX. The best solution is still a custom action executed when clicking browse button.

You can find a sample custom action here: http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/ca.htm

Answer (score 1):

None of the above or anywhere else worked for me.  What did work is so more simple and straight forward.

Like many, I need to prompt the Installer user for the target locations of SQL Server .mdf and .ldf files, which will likely reside outside of any pre-installation Directory structure.  In fact, my preceding Dialog prompts the user for the target database server.  Given that, I then custom act on that preceding Dialog's "Next" button to (a) find the mdf & ldf paths of the server's "master" database and then (b) default the new database's respective paths to those of the master db.

But hours of frustration making PathEdit play nice with BrowseDlg proved futile.  What I ended up doing was creating a placeholder Property called PATH_TEMP_BROWSE.  It is the "SetTarget" call in the BrowseDlg that forces us to enlist the Wix Directory tree.  Get rid of that line in your own custom rip-off of BrowseDlg and instead pass around the user's selected directory via PATH_TEMP_BROWSE thusly:

```
<Dialog Id="DirectoryBrowserDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="Dir Browse">
  <Control Id="Path" Type="PathEdit" X="25" Y="202" Width="320" Height="18" Property="PATH_TEMP_BROWSE" Indirect="yes" />
  <Control Id="OK" Type="PushButton" X="240" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUIOK)">
    <!-- NO! -->
    <!--<Publish Event="SetTargetPath" Value="[_BrowseProperty]">1</Publish>-->
    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
  </Control>

  ...

  <Control Id="DirectoryCombo" Type="DirectoryCombo" X="70" Y="55" Width="220" Height="80" Property="PATH_TEMP_BROWSE" Indirect="yes" Fixed="yes" Remote="yes">
    <Subscribe Event="IgnoreChange" Attribute="IgnoreChange" />
  </Control>

  ...

  <Control Id="DirectoryList" Type="DirectoryList" X="25" Y="83" Width="320" Height="98" Property="PATH_TEMP_BROWSE" Sunken="yes" Indirect="yes" TabSkip="no" />

  ...

</Dialog>
```

Then, to make use of my pop-up modal DirectoryBrowserDlg within my installation Dialog that prompts the user for the new database name as well as its logical files...

```
<Control  Id="MdfPath"
          Type="PathEdit"
          X="37"
          Y="184"
          Width="313"
          Height="18"
          Property="PATH_DBMDFCS"
          />
<Control  Id="MdfBrowse"
          Type="PushButton"
          X="350"
          Y="184"
          Width="22"
          Height="17"
          Text="Browse..."
          >
  <Publish Property="PATH_TEMP_BROWSE" Value="PATH_DBMDFCS" Order="1">1</Publish>
  <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="DirectoryBrowserDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
  <Publish Property="PATH_DBMDFCS" Value="PATH_TEMP_BROWSE" Order="3" />
</Control>
```

Do the same for your .ldf file.

K.I.S.S

Comment: I got this to work as well, just note that you do need to set `PATH_TEMP_BROWSE` to a default value. I did the following `<Property Id="PATH_TEMP_BROWSE" Value="C:\" />` in my Product.wxs file. If you don't, you may get error 2343 - "Specified path is empty."

Answer (score -2):

I have a very easy solution. We can use the ConfigurableDirectory attribute of feature to enable the browse directory. It works well for me.

```
<Feature Id="OCMSnapshotConfigAppFeature" Title="OCM Snapshot Configuration" Level="1" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLDIR">
```