# Creating wix installer to install at multiple paths

Tags: wix, installation

I am trying to create a wix installer which will install to multiple paths (these location will be calculated at runtime through customactions). Installer will have multiple features.
e.g feature1 and feature2 will be installed on path1, feature1 and feature3 will be intalled on path2, and so on.

is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be quite painless.

Idea is simple:

1) Create new Wix custom dialog, and hook it up between default dialogs.

2) In the custom dialog, use folder browser dialog, and set the property value.

3) You then later can use property value in order to show where you want to install it.

This should get you going; [Use WiX browser dialog to set edit box value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496995/use-wix-browser-dialog-to-set-edit-box-value)