# Values of multiple PathEdit controls to multiple properties

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I want to build an Installer with Microsoft Wix 3.8 that actually just registers some COM-components and creates some shortcuts to a program on a server share. Just to point that out in advance: This program is a legacy tool and the way it's launched or used won't be changed, unfortunately.
So I need my installer to ask for three paths: The server installation path (as unc), and two additional paths, also on the server (also as unc).

I'm already struggling with the first path. As soon as I add it it seems to be hard wired to some directory I have to specify in my product.wxs.

That's how my product.wxs looks like:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">
  <Product Id="613A5421-BF59-46DD-B363-05E55587B89F" Name="Test Client" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0" Manufacturer="Blub AG" UpgradeCode="A451E5EB-4AED-4A8A-ACBC-F65A34E86D45">
    <Package Id="*" InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
    <MediaTemplate />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="images\background.bmp" />    
    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />    
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
    <Feature Id='Complete' Title='Foobar 1.0' Description='The complete package.'>
      <Feature Id='TestClient' Title='Test Client' Description='Test Client' Level='1'>
        <ComponentGroupRef Id='ProductComponents' />
      </Feature>
    </Feature>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK20"/>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="ExpoWin" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" >
      <Component Id="ProductComponent">
        <File Source="Blub.txt" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

(In my original code I replaced the WixUI_InstallDir with my own version so that I can modify it to ask for three paths. But to point out my problem the code above should suffice)
I don't want the "INSTALLFOLDER" to be linked to any Directory. But as soon as I change

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />
```

to

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="SERVERPATH" />
<Property Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="c:\program files (x86)\TestClient" />
```

and run the installer I get a "2343 error":

*DEBUG: Error 2343:  Specified path is empty.
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2343. The arguments are: , ,*

Well hopefully this question is easy to answer. I've been searching the web for hours. Probably I haven't understood the concept of properties entirely. Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following explanation might not be valid 100%, it's the way that I explain it to myself ;-).
WiX takes the value of a property and uses it to resolve the path. In the first case it finds the property in the directory structure, so the path can be resolved. In the second example `SERVERPATH` is just the string `SERVERPATH`, so it can't find anything. You have to either set it using a registry search or to a concrete path or by a custom action.
What worked great for me in the UI and custom dialogs (I had a similar requirement with the installation folder and an additional path) was the [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21785487/1785391).

Here is an example for setting it via a custom action (`INSTALLLOCATION` in my case was read from the registry, but it can be any path; `INSTALLDIR` is defined by the directory structure in the WiX source file):

```
<CustomAction Id="SetINSTALLDIR"  Property="INSTALLDIR" Value="[INSTALLLOCATION]" Execute="firstSequence" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="SetINSTALLDIR" After="AppSearch">INSTALLLOCATION</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
<InstallUISequence>
        <Custom Action="SetINSTALLDIR" After="AppSearch">INSTALLLOCATION</Custom>
</InstallUISequence>
```

Using the method described in the answer above I have the following in my WiX source file:

```
<Directory Id="LUCENEFOLDER" SourceName="LuceneIndex" />
```

The path is then set in the UI on a custom dialog by the following snippet:

```
<Control Id="LuceneFolderLabel" Type="Text" X="5" Y="155" Width="200" Height="10" Text="Folder containing Multiindex.config of Lucene:" TabSkip="yes" />
<Control Type="PathEdit" Id="LuceneFolder" Width="200" Height="17" X="5" Y="165" Property="LUCENEFOLDER"/>
<Control Id="LuceneFolderBrwsButton" Type="PushButton" Width="56" Height="17" X="210" Y="164" Text="Change..." >
  <Publish Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="LUCENEFOLDER" Order="1">1</Publish>
  <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
</Control>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It led me into the right direction although I endet up doing it in a different way. Thanks for your way of explaining how properties are supposed to be used. Makes sense to me ;)
Btw. I solved my problem with custom actions as described here: http://community.saasgrid.com/developers/b/team/archive/2011/02/17/wix-managed-custom-actions-openfiledialog-example.aspx