# WiX Cannot input session value to a text box (with CustomAction)

Tags: .net, iis, wix

Environment: Windows 7(x64), WiX toolset 3.10

I made an additional window to a sequence of "WixUI_Mondo", to make the window which an user can install IIS role and .NET Framework 3.5 features...even if an environment requires a OS media containing SxS package. (I know VbScriptCall is not recommended, but BrowseDlg doesn't work well in my environment...and .NET code might not be available in this phase.):

1) My code below can call CustomAction and open BrowseForFolder, but its return value doesn't synchronize with SXS_PATH property or SourcePathEdit textbox, what is wrong?

Fragment is below:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
  <Fragment>
    <CustomAction Id="FolderExplorer" BinaryKey="FolderExplorer.vb" Impersonate="yes" Return="check" Execute="immediate" VBScriptCall="GetSxsPath" />
    <Binary Id="FolderExplorer.vb" SourceFile="OpenVbScriptFolderExplorer.vbs"/>
    <Property Id="ONOFF_PROPERTY" Secure="yes" Value="0" />
    <Property Id="SXS_PATH" Value="C:\" />
    <UI>
      <Dialog Id="WindowsServerRolesAndFeaturesDlg"
              Width="370" Height="270"
              Title="[ProductName] [Setup]" NoMinimize="yes">
        <Control Id="RdxOnlineOffline" Type="RadioButtonGroup" X="40" Y="63" Width="200" Height="35" Property="ONOFF_PROPERTY" Text="Choose install method：">
            <RadioButtonGroup Property="ONOFF_PROPERTY">
                     <RadioButton Value="0" X="0" Y="0" Width="300" Height="15" Text="local package or online windows update available" />
                     <RadioButton Value="1" X="0" Y="20" Width="300" Height="15" Text="Require offline install from a media" />
            </RadioButtonGroup>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="SourcePath" Type="Text"
                 X="45" Y="98" Width="200" Height="15"
                 TabSkip="no" Text="Input Sxs path when offline(&amp;U):" />
        <Control Id="SourcePathEdit" Type="Edit"
                 X="45" Y="110" Width="220" Height="18"
                 Property="SXS_PATH" Text="{80}">
                 <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[ONOFF_PROPERTY <> "1"]]></Condition>
                 <Condition Action="enable"><![CDATA[ONOFF_PROPERTY = "1"]]></Condition>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="SourcePathButton" Type="PushButton"
                 X="265" Y="110" Width="56" Height="18"
                 Default="yes" Text="Refer..">
                 <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[ONOFF_PROPERTY <> "1"]]></Condition>
                 <Condition Action="enable"><![CDATA[ONOFF_PROPERTY = "1"]]></Condition>
                 <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="FolderExplorer">1</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton"
                 X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17"
                 Text="Back(&amp;B)">
          <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">1</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton"
                 X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17"
                 Default="yes" Text="次へ(&amp;N)">
          <!--<Publish Event="SpawnWaitDialog" Value="WaitForCostingDlg">CostingComplete = 1</Publish>-->
          <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="SetupTypeDlg">ProductID</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton"
                 X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17"
                 Cancel="yes" Text="Cancel">
          <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap"
                 X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44"
                 TabSkip="no" Text="WixUI_Bmp_Banner" />
        <Control Id="Description" Type="Text"
                 X="25" Y="23" Width="280" Height="15"
                 Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes">
          <Text>Install Windows IIS role and .NET Framework features</Text>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line"
                 X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
        <Control Id="Title" Type="Text"
                 X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15"
                 Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes">
          <Text>{\WixUI_Font_Title}Set IIS role and .NET Framework 3.5 features</Text>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line"
                 X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
      </Dialog>
    </UI>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

VBScript is below:

```js
Option Explicit

public sub GetSxsPath()

    Dim objShell
    Dim objFolder
    Dim objFolderItem
    Dim strPath

    Const WINDOW_HANDLE = 0  
    Const NO_OPTIONS = 0  

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")  
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder _  
        (WINDOW_HANDLE, "Choose SxS Folder for IIS role and .NET features", NO_OPTIONS)         

    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
    strPath = objFolderItem.Path

    MsgBox(strPath)

    if Err.Number = 0 then
        Session.Property("SXS_PATH") = strPath
    end if

    exit sub

end sub
```

2)If 1) is successful, I want to use another custom action to call DOS command DISM, with setting SXS_PATH. Any ideas?

```xml
    @echo off

SET SXS_PATH=D:\sources\sxs ←here insert the path 1)SourcePathEdit value...




        DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /Source:%SXS_PATH%
        DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole /FeatureName:IIS-RequestFiltering /FeatureName:IIS-Security /FeatureName:IIS-HttpLogging /FeatureName:IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerManagementTools /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementConsole /FeatureName:IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility /FeatureName:IIS-Metabase /FeatureName:IIS-WebServer /FeatureName:IIS-Performance /FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionStatic /FeatureName:IIS-CommonHttpFeatures /FeatureName:IIS-StaticContent /FeatureName:IIS-DefaultDocument /FeatureName:IIS-DirectoryBrowsing /FeatureName:IIS-HttpErrors /FeatureName:IIS-ApplicationDevelopment /FeatureName:IIS-ASPNET /FeatureName:IIS-NetFxExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIExtensions /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIFilter /all /Source:%SXS_PATH%
```

Answer (score 0):

This is self-reply:

It is not a right answer to "CustomAction", but at least I find a solution what I want: to set Explorer selection value to a WiX editbox. 
(reading an article [Use WiX browser dialog to set edit box value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496995/use-wix-browser-dialog-to-set-edit-box-value) and GitHub sample https://github.com/misohena/simple_wix_template)

It seems that my installer groans Error Code 2343 if a directory tag set ("SxSFolder" entry (D) ) doesn't exist which is referred by the property (value (B) and property (A)(C))

I'm still studying CustomAction to call DOS DISM command:
Thank you:

Below is a long but working sample:

Main.wxs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Name="FugaFuga 1.12.0" Id="MY-UID" UpgradeCode="MY-UID" Language="1041" Codepage="932" Version="1.12.0" Manufacturer="HogeHoge">
        <Package Id="*" Keywords="Installer" Description="FugaFuga 1.12.0 Installer" Comments="FugaFuga is trademark of HogeHoge Inc." Manufacturer="HogeHoge" InstallerVersion="100" Languages="1041" Compressed="yes" SummaryCodepage="932" />
        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="Sample.cab" EmbedCab="yes" DiskPrompt="CD-ROM 1" />
        <Property Id="DiskPrompt" Value="HogeHoge FugaFuga 1.12.0 Installer [1]" />
        <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLDIR" />
        <Property Id="SXS_PATH" Secure="yes" Value="SxSFolder" /><!--(C)-->

        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PFiles">
                <Directory Id="FugaFuga" Name="FugaFuga">
                    <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="Hoge 1.0">
                        <Component Id="FugaFugaLibrary" Guid="MY-UID">
                            <File Id="test.bat" Name="test.bat" DiskId="1" Source="test.bat" KeyPath="yes" />
                        </Component>
                    </Directory>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
            <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="Programs">
            </Directory>
            <Directory Id="SxSFolder" Name="SxS" /><!--(D)-->

            <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop" />
        </Directory>


        <Feature Id="Complete" Title="FugaFuga 1.12.0" Description="Complete Package" Display="expand" Level="1" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLDIR">
            <Feature Id="MainProgram" Title="Program" Description="Main Program" Level="1">
                <ComponentRef Id="FugaFugaLibrary" />
            </Feature>
        </Feature>
        <UI Id="MyWixUI_Mondo">
            <UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />

            <DialogRef Id="WindowsServerRolesAndFeaturesDlg" />
            <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="WindowsServerRolesAndFeaturesDlg" Order="2">
             LicenseAccepted = "1"
            </Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="SetupTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WindowsServerRolesAndFeaturesDlg">
             1
            </Publish>
              <Publish Dialog="WindowsServerRolesAndFeaturesDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">LicenseAccepted = "1"</Publish>
              <Publish Dialog="WindowsServerRolesAndFeaturesDlg" Control="Next" Event="SetTargetPath" Value="[SXS_PATH]" Order="2">1</Publish>
              <Publish Dialog="WindowsServerRolesAndFeaturesDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[SXS_PATH]" Order="1">1</Publish><!--(B)-->
              <Publish Dialog="WindowsServerRolesAndFeaturesDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
        </UI>
        <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

WindowsServerRolesAndFeaturesDlg.wxs

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
  <Fragment>
    <Property Id="ONOFF_PROPERTY" Secure="yes" Value="0" />
    <UI>
      <Dialog Id="WindowsServerRolesAndFeaturesDlg"
              Width="370" Height="270"
              Title="[ProductName] [Setup]" NoMinimize="yes">
        <Control Id="RdxOnlineOffline" Type="RadioButtonGroup" X="40" Y="63" Width="200" Height="35" Property="ONOFF_PROPERTY" Text="Choose install method：">
            <RadioButtonGroup Property="ONOFF_PROPERTY">
                     <RadioButton Value="0" X="0" Y="0" Width="300" Height="15" Text="local package or online windows update available" />
                     <RadioButton Value="1" X="0" Y="20" Width="300" Height="15" Text="Require offline install from a media" />
            </RadioButtonGroup>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="SourcePath" Type="Text"
                 X="45" Y="98" Width="200" Height="15"
                 TabSkip="no" Text="Input Sxs path when offline(&amp;U)(&amp;U):" />

        <Control Type="PathEdit" Id="TxtDir" X="45" Y="110" Width="220" Height="18" Property="SXS_PATH" Indirect="yes"><!--(A)-->
                 <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[ONOFF_PROPERTY <> "1"]]></Condition>
                 <Condition Action="enable"><![CDATA[ONOFF_PROPERTY = "1"]]></Condition>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="ChangeFolder" Type="PushButton" X="265" Y="110" Width="56" Height="18" Text="Browse...">
                 <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[ONOFF_PROPERTY <> "1"]]></Condition>
                 <Condition Action="enable"><![CDATA[ONOFF_PROPERTY = "1"]]></Condition>
        </Control>

        <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton"
                 X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17"
                 Text="Back(&amp;B)">
          <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">1</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton"
                 X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17"
                 Default="yes" Text="Next(&amp;N)">
          <!--<Publish Event="SpawnWaitDialog" Value="WaitForCostingDlg">CostingComplete = 1</Publish>-->
          <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="SetupTypeDlg">ProductID</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton"
                 X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17"
                 Cancel="yes" Text="Cancel">
          <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap"
                 X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44"
                 TabSkip="no" Text="WixUI_Bmp_Banner" />
        <Control Id="Description" Type="Text"
                 X="25" Y="23" Width="280" Height="15"
                 Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes">
          <Text>Install Windows IIS role and .NET Framework features</Text>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line"
                 X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
        <Control Id="Title" Type="Text"
                 X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15"
                 Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes">
          <Text>{\WixUI_Font_Title}Set IIS role and .NET Framework 3.5 features</Text>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line"
                 X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
      </Dialog>
    </UI>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```