# Standard approach to the server environment for the distributable asp.net package

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, wix

For web application package vendors providing installer for some reason:

Would you share the "standard" approach to prepare fixed server environment for an asp.net application package? But some conditions I have:

1)My application requires iis, .net framework and sql server.

2)Windows Server itself, Sql Server licence and media is not provided by my company, end users provide them.(Usually standard edition.) When visiting end user site, Windows Os is already installed, but SQLserver media is not.

3)Install paths of sqlserver program, datas(mdf, ldf) can be changed by users according to server condition.

4)Users and my company officers don't want to change operational circumstances of endusers. Just want to change install procedure currently by manual manpower visiting physical sites of users.

5)Developper Environment:Visual Studio 2010.

6)We don't afford to buy Install Shield, or other non-free software.

I assume a concept that can be fulfilled by custom actions of WiX. But if such server environment should not be contained to a distributable installer which faces against the hostile circumstances of user servers ( install might fail for unknown reasons), I don't need uninstall function to my installer. But if WiX designers don't expect such installer, I might be in wrong path...

Any ideas?

Comment: There's no such thing as a standard approach, everything is specific to the individual requirements of the situation. You decide what you need, follow the official documentation for configuring those items, and then make any settings changes which are needed for the particular circumstances. However, creating an installer probably doesn't replace having to visit manually, unless you trust the user to set the correct configuration options in the app and in their server. It's quite common for application vendors to request RDP access to the target server so they can perform the install remotely.

Comment: Alternatively, a lot of applications these days are delivered via containerisation, either on-premises or in an off-site cloud environment, which can make deployments simpler and more reliable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @ADyson, but I am afraid you don't understand what I wrote. I don't think Wix can install windows os. English is my second language, so i'm sorry if i wrote wrongly.

Comment: I want to know about asp.net package vendors which providing application installer for some reason. Currently my application dont have installer.

Comment: "Windows Server itself, Sql Server licence and media is not provided by my company, end users provide them." I took this to mean the customer would be providing you with a windows and SQL server install. You mean they only give you a license and you are required to install it yourself? You generally cannot do this without physical access to the data centre, unless it's all virtualised using VMWare or something, in which case it should be possible to use remote tools to create a VM, assuming the customer gives you access to it. Maybe you should just ask them to provide the server if they can.

Comment: P.S. I know you are looking for application install packages. My point was that an installer isn't necessarily the best solution to your problem. I suggested an alternative approach to consider, that's all.

Comment: I understand I didn't provide the server status when our company physically visit enduser sites for manual installation. I added it. Sorry.

Comment: Almost nearly the same tedious routine except the install path for many customers, one of the reasons to make installer for me....

Comment: yeah if the server O/S is already there there's probably no reason you can't make an installer.